# ExtJS4: Add field to form panel but not want it to be rendered by panel

Tags: forms, panel, extjs4, field

I have a static html form layout where i add extjs form fields using the "renderTo" config. In order to have form validation and simple submit methods i want to add the fields to a form panel. As the layout is managed by the html frame i don't want the form to be rendered by the panel (panel has html frame as contentEl and this should be used as is).

In extjs3 i could achieve this by adding the field not to the panel but to the BasicForm (formpanel.getForm().add(...)) but in extjs4 this method seems to be gone.

How can i do this using extjs4?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [Ext.form.Basic](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic), you might need to write a simple container to use the basic form the way you want.

Comment: The problem is that i don't know how to add fields to the Ext.form.Basic. It has no add-method or something like this. But without adding the fields they are not validated or submitted, are they?

Comment: You need a container that hooks up to the basic form, like Ext.form.Panel does. But if you don't want to render your items you need your own (dummy-)container. But this would be just a workaround for your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have a Panel that uses the contentEl to render HTML into its body, I recommend to stick with this approach:
Replace the panel with an Ext.form.Panel instance - the configuration, particularly the contentEl config - can remain unchanged.

The code provided here will override a standard Ext class (Ext.layout.Layout) and introduce support for a 'renderItemTo' config property on child items of any Ext container or panel instance (including Ext.form.Panel).
The value of the config property should be the ID of an already rendered DOM node, e.g. a DIV element that is part of the HTML fragment used in as the contentEl of the parent container's body.

```
Ext.require(['Ext.layout.Layout'], function() {
    Ext.override(Ext.layout.Layout, {
        renderItem: function (item, target, position) {
            if(item.renderItemTo) {
                // render 'renderItemTo' components into the specified DOM element
                item.render(item.renderItemTo, 1);
                // don't allow container layout to seize the component
                item.layoutManagedHeight = 2;
                item.layoutManagedWidth = 2;
            } else {
                // just use standard Ext code for non-renderItemTo components
                this.callOverridden(arguments);
            }
        },
        isValidParent: function(item, target, position) {
            // signal Ext that we are OK with were our 'renderItemTo' component is right now
            // otherwise it would get moved during the layout process
            return item.renderItemTo ? true : this.callOverridden(arguments);
        }
    });
});
```

Usage:

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    contentEl: 'form', // the DOM element ID that holds the HTML fragment for the body
    title: 'My FormPanel with special FX',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            renderItemTo: 'text1', // the ID of a DOM element inside the HTML fragment
            fieldLabel: 'Label 1',
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            renderItemTo: 'text2', // the ID of a DOM element inside the HTML fragment
            fieldLabel: 'Label 2'
        }
    ]
});
```

I uploaded a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mistaecko/9KpBN/) to JSFiddle (note: resize the window if you experience a render problem - this is related to JSFiddle, not my override).

Comment: Great work. Thanks! Just one question. You used layoutManagedHeight and layoutManagedWidth. This properties seems to be undocumentated. Do i have to worry about them going away in future releases?

Comment: I guess you have. Not so because it is undocumented (the entire internal workings of the Ext layout system can be considered undocumented IMHO), rather because Ext 4.1 will bring extensive changes to the way layouting works. This is in order to tackle performance problems introduced in Ext4.0 related to the layouting and rendering engine. See [this forum post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?142811-Ext-JS-4.1-Layout-and-Rendering-Performance).

Comment: I should add that the opposite approach (writing a custom container for the the Ext.form.Basic class) would very likely include a much higher number of lines of code, with an equivalent probability to break in future Ext versions.

Comment: Yes you are right. I think a feature like this should be added to ExtJS4 (in ExtJS3 it was possible). Maybe i have to ask for help again for ExtJS4.1 as the whole layout system is quite complex to understand :(

Comment: If you think the answer is great you could upvote it as well ;)

Comment: Has anyone figured out a similar approach for 4.1?

Comment: Would need an update for 4.1 too. Tried myself but failed up to now. Just figured out that renderItem method is not called for every element but only for the containing panel. So the renderItemTo property has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

After digging through the layout system of ExtJS 4.1 i implemented a custom layout which moves the items after rendering to the desired position in the fixed markup. The result is the same as for the ExtJS 4.0.7 version from this thread. It seams to work for the ExtJS standard fields. I have some problems with my custom fields though.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.layout.Fixed', {
  extend: 'Ext.layout.container.Auto',
  alias: 'layout.uxfixed',
  afterRenderItem: function(item) {
    // move items with renderToFixedMarkup to desired position
    if (item.renderToFixedMarkup) {
      var target = Ext.getDom(item.renderToFixedMarkup);
      this.moveItem(item, target);
    }
  },
  isValidParent: function(item, target, position) {
    // items with renderToFixedMarkup property are always positioned correctly
    return (item.renderToFixedMarkup) ? true : this.callOverridden(arguments);
  }
});
```

It can be used by setting "layout: 'uxfixed'" on the panel and the "renderToFixedMarkup" config on the items.